# What is this code mean? Is it anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I am studying about the React using textbook. There are some codes I cant understand in the book.

```
const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
}
```

I know the anonymous function in the javascript.

```
(a, b, c) => {
}
```

But, what is this?

```
store => next => action => {
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a higher-order function, i.e. a function that returns a function. It means the same as

```
store => next => {
    return action => { }
}
```

Comment: @NJS right, so it's a function that returns a function that returns a function.

Comment: Then, this code mean same?
(store) => {
 return (next) => {
      return (action) => { }
 }
}

Comment: thank you for your kind answer~!